# Which programing language or API for a real time web dashboard?

Tags: web, real-time, dashboard

I have a project to realize: a real-time web dashboard presenting statistics computed from the information of a log file, updated in real time too, and
I wonder what programming language, API or technology to use for that. Could you advise me? thank you !
I have heard about the proper websocket technology for a real-time application, which can be used in php java python and NodeJS. Which language would you advise me if I were to use this technology?

Answer (score 0):

I think questions like this are generally discouraged as being too broad - and not really about a programming problem.

From my side, my recommendation is clear: Check out WAMP (http://wamp-proto.org) and the Crossbar.io WAMP router (http://crossbar.io). There's an (old) demo for using this for a live Web dashboard at https://demo.crossbar.io/dashboard/index.html as well.

Full disclosure: I'm part of the team working on these technologies, so I'm probably strongly biased, but it's open source and does what you want, so I think it's a valid recommendation. There are certainly other technologies out there that work for this as well.